# How to use function in_array with CodeIgneter

Tags: php, frameworks, codeigniter-2

I am trying to use the PHP function **in_array** within a view using CodeIgneter.

This is the method

```
class User_details extends CI_Model {

public function checkID(){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM users");

return $query->result_array();
```

}

This is the controller

```
$this->load->model('user_details');

$data['allUserID'] = $this->user_details->checkID();
$this->load->view('user_details/content',$data);
```

This is the script I am trying to use in the view

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(4);//user's id for example: 218


if(in_array($id,$allUserID)){
echo 'exists';
} else {
echo 'does not exist';
}
```

Unfortunately he script does not work as expected.

If I check the array using **print_r($allUserID)** I get following result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 217 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 218 ...
...and so on...
```

Last week I started learning CodeIgneter and I did not understand its approach yet.

Comment: there is nothing related to `codeigneter` and `in_array` its a php function used to find something in `array`. you are using it in a wrong way. it is used for single dimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array()` accept single dimensional array and you are passing two dimensional array. Try converting it to single dimensional array like

```
$array = array_map('current', $allUserID);

if(in_array($id, $array)){
 echo 'exists';
} else {
  echo 'does not exist';
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Yes, sure: I was using in_array() in a wrong way.